# rlm_eap error running freeradius in openwrt

Tags: linux, beagleboneblack, openwrt, freeradius

I am running openwrt on beagle bone black board. I am getting following error while running freeradius.

```
radiusd -X
rlm_eap: SSL error error:02001002:lib(2):func(1):reason(2)                          
rlm_eap_tls: Error reading certificate file /etc/freeradius2/certs/server.pem       
rlm_eap: Failed to initialize type tls                                              
/etc/freeradius2/eap.conf[17]: Instantiation failed for module "eap"                
/etc/freeradius2/sites/default[312]: Failed to find "eap" in the "modules" section. 
/etc/freeradius2/sites/default[254]: Errors parsing authenticate section.
```

when i checked there is no "cert" directory present in /etc/freeradius2/. Plz help

Answer (score 1):

Problem was solved after installing freeradius2-democerts_2.2.7-1_omap.ipk

after installing following error might trouble:

```
Debug:  Module: Checking authorize {...} for more modules to load
Error: /etc/freeradius2/sites/default[160]: Failed to find "reject" in the "modules" section.
Error: /etc/freeradius2/sites/default[69]: Errors parsing authorize section.
```

to resolve this go to /etc/freeradius2/sites/default line no. 160. comment the line which has reject word.

Comment: Helped me fix my Problem. installing `freeradius2-democerts` fix it. `opkg install  freeradius2-democerts`